# Removing Nativescript application from a device, Application Settings

Tags: android, nativescript

I am having trouble with a Nativescript App which use the **Application Settings Module**,

When i **remove this App** from an Android Phone, even if i clear App Data and Cache before uninstall, and i reinstall it, the **settings** set earlier (before unistall) **seems to be still there**,

Does anyone else has ever encountered this issue ?

Regards,
Kansen

Comment: reinstalling the app clears the app settings, if the settings persist then it sounds like they are coded that way within your app

Comment: mast3rd3mon, thanks for your reply, i know that should be the expected behaviour, but for instance, i still have a "cookie" value in AppSettings after unistall/reinstall, which has no sense since i have not logged in yet. 
" if the settings persist then it sounds like they are coded that way within your app" , do you mean that there is a way to keep the App Settings even if app has been remove ?

Comment: no, i mean that you might have coded the values into your app

Comment: Ok, that's why i took this cookie example which is not hard coded, but set when we got a response from the web service, but i can access the old cookie value in my fresh new installed app.

Answer (score 1):

```
<application

    android:allowBackup="false">...</application>
```

Try this in AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Thanks for your reply, the problem was isolated on only 1 customer's smartphone...